# groupby shifting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I turn this:

```
 year artist           genre    genre_sales
 1999      A        Pop/Rock             10
 1999      B        Hip/Hop              15
 1999      C        Country               8            
 2000      A        Pop/Rock             11
 2000      B        Hip/Hop              14
 2000      D        Jazz                  1
 2001      B        Hip/Hop              18
 2001      C        Country              10
```

Into this:

```
 year artist           genre    genre_sales
 1999      A        Pop/Rock            Nan 
 1999      B        Hip/Hop             Nan
 1999      C        Country             Nan
 2000      A        Pop/Rock             10
 2000      B        Hip/Hop              15
 2000      D        Jazz            (1999 Jazz sales despite D not releasing in '99)
 2001      B        Hip/Hop              14
 2001      C        Country         (2000 country values, not the 8 from '99)
```

I saw the groupby-shift question and cookbook page and assumed I could do something like:

```
df.groupby(['year','artist'])['genre_sales'].shift(1)
```

or

```
df.groupby(['year','genre','artist'])['genre_sales'].shift(1)
```

but I think those would only work if artists produced one album per year.

Current 'Genre Sales' is annual sales in the artist's genre for that year. I'm trying to get the PREVIOUS year's 'Genre Sales' in a row with each artist. Each genre will have multiple artists every year, and each artist could have zero or multiple entries in that genre in a given year.

Comment: Actually I can't figured out how turning the first dataframe to the second one. May you please be more specific (which function would you like to implement?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df_prev = df.copy()

df[     'prev_year'] = df[     'year'] - 1    
df_prev['prev_year'] = df_prev['year']
df_prev[     'year'] = df_prev['year'] + 1

df2 = df.merge( df_prev, how='outer', on=['year','prev_year','artist','genre'], 
                suffixes=['','_prev'] )

df2.sort(['artist','genre','year']).fillna(0)

    year artist     genre  genre_sales  prev_year  genre_sales_prev
0   1999      A  Pop/Rock           10       1998                 0
3   2000      A  Pop/Rock           11       1999                10
9   2001      A  Pop/Rock            0       2000                11
1   1999      B   Hip/Hop           15       1998                 0
4   2000      B   Hip/Hop           14       1999                15
6   2001      B   Hip/Hop           18       2000                14
11  2002      B   Hip/Hop            0       2001                18
2   1999      C   Country            8       1998                 0
8   2000      C   Country            0       1999                 8
7   2001      C   Country           10       2000                 0
12  2002      C   Country            0       2001                10
5   2000      D      Jazz            1       1999                 0
10  2001      D      Jazz            0       2000                 1
```

Comment: what's going on with df and df_prev at the top? is df_prev a copy of the original?

Comment: Oops, yeah, it's just a copy.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using the groupby-apply combination

create a function that is applied to each segment and adds a new column that is the target column shifted:

```
def shiftCol(grp, newCol, col):
    grp[newCol] = grp[col].shift()
    return grp
```

Then just call the function, specifying the name of the columns to shift

```
df.groupby(['artist']).apply(shiftCol, newCol = 'prev_genre_sales',col = 'genre_sales')
```